# Prevent null values in foreign key, Unable to modify table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have become null values in foreign keys and I don't know what causes it.

The following error occurs:

'Venues (Soccer)' table

- Unable to modify table.

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'City_id', table 'League Espania.Soccer. Tmp_Ver

The statement has been terminated.

Error in management studio:
[image: error in microsoft sql server management studio]

Answer (score 0):

Learn TSQL and you will understand the problems you have created for yourself. And learn to ask smart questions - posting an image of your screen that is mostly an error message is not useful. Your table contains rows where the value of City_ID is null and therefore inconsistent with your attempt to change the definition of the table. You need to either remove those rows or change their NULL values to valid ones **before** you add the foreign key.

You could also change your approach and allow NULL values for this column. That makes little logical sense but would allow you to define your foreign key with the rows that currently exist.

And one last suggestion. Do NOT start using names that violate the rules for [regular identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-2017). This will only cause you much pain and work as you learn tsql. You already have a database with a space in the name.

Comment: THANKS A LOT SIR.CAN i HAVE FURTHER COMMUNACTIONS WITH U?